# Could not deduce template type for variadic template

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates, template-argument-deduction

I have created simple callback based event manager and it works, but I have some errors with zero template arguments.

```cpp
class event_manager
{
public:
    template <typename... T>
    static void register_event(const unsigned long e, std::function<void(T...)> ec)
    {
        events.insert({ e, ec });
    }

    template <typename... T>
    static void fire_event(const unsigned long e, T... args)
    {
        for (auto it : events)
        {
            if (it.first == e)
            {
                boost::any_cast<std::function<void(T...)>>(it.second)(args...);
            }
        }
    }
private:
    static std::unordered_multimap<unsigned int, boost::any> events;
};
```

And I'm using this code to add callback:

```cpp
event_manager::register_event<unsigned int>(DVU_EVENT_KEY_PRESSED, [](unsigned int key)
{
    //Works!
});

event_manager::register_event(DVU_EVENT_IDLE, []()
{
    //Could not deduce template argument
});
```

And the second question:
Is it possible to change code to remove `<unsigned int>`-like template specification?

Example:

```cpp
event_manager::register_event(DVU_EVENT_KEY_PRESSED, [](unsigned int key){}));
```

Comment: The first one doesn't deduce anything. You explicitly told it what to use. Take out that list and it also won't work. Put an explicit list into the second and it will.

Comment: A lambda is unrelated to `std::function`. Template type deduction tries to find types `T...` such that the type `std::function<void(T...)>` becomes the same as the type of the argument (the lambda). But that's impossible since those two are unrelated.

Comment: @chris, but what I have to put into the second call? It has no template parameters.

Comment: You probably also want to look up `e` in `events`, rather than just iterating over the whole map. Otherwise, no point in having a map...

Comment: @DejaVu, An empty list.

Comment: @chris, I've tried `event_manager::register_event<>(DVU_EVENT_IDLE, [](){});` and it said the same.

Comment: I don't see a reason for that to not work and the first one to work, but OK, I could just be crazy.

Comment: @chris, the first one causes IntelliSense errors (no function template matches the argument list), but it compiles and works.

Comment: This design is ridiculously unsafe.  The types used in `register_event` have to match the types used in `fire_event` exactly -- doing that with type deduction is very fragile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since a lambda is just a functor with `operator()`, you could just have an overload that ends up deducing it:

```
template <typename F>
static void register_event(const unsigned long e, F f) 
{
    register_event(e, f, &F::operator());
}

template <typename F, typename R, typename... T>
static void register_event(const unsigned long e, F& f, 
    R (F::*method)(T...) const) 
{
    std::function<R(T...)> func = f;
    events.insert({ e, func });
}
```

Maybe either require that `R == void` or `static_assert` it or something.

Comment: Wow, it works and solved my problems, but it doesn't work with normal functions.

Comment: @DejaVu Usually this is a bad idea, because C++14 brings in `auto` arguments to lambdas, and this technique fails.

Comment: @Yakk You couldn't use a generic lambda in this context anyway. You need to store it by specific type.

Comment: @Barry Generic lambdas can be stored in `std::function`s just fine.  Its genericity is hidden, but it works just peachy.

Comment: @Yakk Right, but I mean, you have to store it by some type, so you'd have to tell the event manager specifically what type you'd want to store it under. At that point, might as well put it in a `std::function` yourself and just use that overload.

Comment: Works fine for lambda and classes with one version on operator() but doesn't work with std::bind

Answer (score 1):

Even the first one doesn't compile [here](https://ideone.com/bC3J38) as you .

`std::function` is not an exact match for the lambda, and as you use variadic template you can't specify all type that way (as you specify the first type and compiler may deduce the rest).

A possible workaround is to pass just the func

```
template <typename Func>
static void register_event(const unsigned long e, Func ec);
```

and reconstruct the std::function with `Func::operator()`

Comment: But it works on MSVS13...
And I need to know argument count and types to use callback.

Comment: @DejaVu something working in one particular version of MSVC doesn't mean it will work in the next update if it violates the C++ standard.

Answer (score 0):

Your design is unsafe, as relying on type deduction to produce exactly matching types is fragile, and your cast requires exactly matching types.

Here is a slightly different design:

```
class event_manager {
public:
  template <typename Signature>
  static void register_event(const unsigned long e, std::function<Signature> ec) {
    events.emplace( e, std::move(ec) );
  }

  template <typename Signature, typename...Ts>
  static void fire_event(const unsigned long e, Ts...&& args) {
    auto r = events.equal_range( e );
    for (auto it = r.first; it != r.second; ++it)
    {
      auto&& f = boost::any_cast<std::function<Signature> const&>(it.second);
      f(std::forward<Ts>(args)...);
    }
  }
private:
  static std::unordered_multimap<unsigned int, boost::any> events;
};
```

here you pass in a function signature at both ends, like `void()` or `void(int)`.  These types have to match exactly.

I perfect forward the arguments to `fire_event` to the function I pull out of the map.

I did some other improvements, like properly moving/emplacing and removed some spurious copies.

Deducing the signature of a lambda is a bad idea for a few reasons.  First, because C++14 `auto` lambdas are coming.  Second, it means the fact that a lambda or function takes a `T const&` or a `T` or whatever "leaks" into how you have to call it (your original implementation required all values be taken by-value).

The signature of a given event now is explicitly listed both where you register it, and where you fire it.  If it doesn't match, it should be easier to notice.

I would also be tempted to `any_cast` to/from a pointer, and assert it is non-null, instead of throwing if you get the signature wrong.